# Масштабирование изображения ImageView при двойном клике

Tags: android, imageview

В ImageView выводится изображение. Как сделать так, чтобы при двойном клике изображение увеличивалось и можно было скроллить как в галерее изображение увеличивается и можно смотреть разные участки изображения увеличив.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826700/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-imageview-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/826886#826886

Comment: а саму галерею вызвать через Intent?

Comment: Изображение не в галерее. Только само приложение знает об изображении

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться готовой библиотекой [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Ну или подсмотреть как она реализована и написать что-то своё ;)